# asp mvc RenderSection and multiple injectors?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

Simple question, I have a simple _Layout page and I am trying to group all my javascript at the bottom, like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
        @RenderSection("ViewCssIncludes")
    </head>
    <body>
        @RenderBody()
        @RenderSection("ViewJavascriptIncludes")
    </body>
</html>
```

Now currently I have 2 partials which include js files relating to their partial (presenter/view js files). So I would be wanting to inject into 1 section from 2 partials, so it would append opposed to overwriting...

Now I am pretty sure you cannot do this, and also I am pretty sure that you cannot call @Section ViewJavacriptIncludes {} from within a partial, but I thought on the off chance that it is possible I would ask in here...

So is it possible to have RenderSections be appended from multiple sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433531/using-sections-in-editor-display-templates/5433722#5433722), it might help.