# Rendering section from partial view using Razor View engine in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have rendering a section in the bottom master layout.  This is typically section to render javascript at the bottom of the page when it renders.  Defining that section in View and _partial views.  When page renders, it renders section from page view but not from the _partial view.

How it is possible to render a section defined in _partial view to main layout?

Comment: @Html.Partial("NameOfPartial", ModelForPartial) if i understood you. It's hard to understand what do you want.

Comment: This is not supported. Sorry. One possible solution is to use custom helpers as shown in this duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433531/using-sections-in-editor-display-templates/5433722#5433722.

Comment: Why can't I access System.Web.Mvc name space in App_Code folder.  I am creating extension method in App_Code class. I am not able to see this name space in the intellisence while adding to the extension class. Neither it is recognize HtmlHelper as know type.

Comment: However namespace System.Web.Mvc is not being coming up in Intellicese but application is compiling so extensions is seems working for me.  Thanks

Comment: Why do you want that? Partial Views should provide some flexibility and should be perfectly reusable. Aren't you creating unwanted dependency (with a Layout view) with that, don't you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Html.RenderAction`/`Html.Action` or use helpers like demonstrated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5433722/290343