# Create a helper function that returns Razor @ tags?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, extension-methods

Struggling to find an answer to my question, as I'm not exactly sure what 'type' a razor tag is.

Essentially I want to create a helper that does something along these lines:

```
public static xxxxxxx ScriptTag(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string url)
{
      return @<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/" + url)" />;
}
```

The reason I want this is that I am implementing the extension methods that are outlined in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433531/using-sections-in-editor-display-templates/5433722#5433722).

Basically rather than have to do:

```
@Html.Resource(@<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>, "js")`
```

I want to be able to do:

```
@Html.Resource(Html.ScriptTag("Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"), "js");
```

Am I reaching beyond the stars here or is this possible?

Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't quite see the usage of the second parameter in your `ScriptTag` helper (`js`). The helper is called ScriptTag so it is pretty obvious that it will render a script. Also why do you need those 2 nested helpers like that when you can directly have:

```
@Html.Resource("Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js", "js")
```

But anyway if you needed such syntax you could use [Razor Templated Delegates](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx):

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static HelperResult ScriptTag(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string url, string type)
    {
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
        var script = new TagBuilder("script");
        script.Attributes["type"] = "text/javascript";
        script.Attributes["src"] = urlHelper.Content("~/" + url);
        return new HelperResult(writer =>
        {
            writer.Write(script.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
        });
    }

    public static IHtmlString Resource(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, HelperResult renderer)
    {
        return renderer;
    }
}
```

As we can see the `Resource` extension method in this case doesn't bring much value.

Comment: ScriptTag actually isn't meant to have that resource string. The resource string is meant to be used in the Resource function only. That way you can render multiple resource types using the Resource function. I'll update the question to remove my mistake.

Comment: Thanks for your help once again BTW!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by creating an extension method for the HtmlHelper type.

For example:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ScriptTag(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string contentPath,
    string scriptType)
{
    var httpContext = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext;

    var scriptTag = String.Format("<script src=\"{0}\" type=\"{1}\"></script>",
        UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl(contentPath, httpContext),
        scriptType);

    return new MvcHtmlString(scriptTag);
}
```

You can then use your custom Html helper method as follows:

```
@Html.ScriptTag("Scripts/jquery1.6.1.min.js", "javascript/text");
```

Answer (score 0):

When the result of a function is plain HTML, I like to use [Razor Helpers](http://codedweapon.com/2012/04/razor-helpers-and-functions/).

Within your view file, create a statement like that:

```
@helper ScriptTag(string url) {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/" + url)"></script>
}
```

then the usage is like

```
@ScriptTag("myScript.js")
```

Razor Helpers return the HTML within the