# RenderSection and EditorForModel in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

This is my _Layout.cshtml

```
<html>
    <head>
        @RenderSection("Script", false)
    </head>
    ...
</html>
```

This is a simple edit page edit.cshtml

```
@model Shop.Models.Product
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

and this is ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Product.cshtml

```
@model Shop.Models.Product
@section Script {
    <script>alert("hello");</script>
}
...
```

`@section Script{...}` does not work in Product.cshtml because of EditorForModel. How can do it?

Comment: Just put the `@section Script{...}` into the `edit.cshtml` and every other View from where you use `Product.cshtml`.

Comment: @nemesv I know it but I need a solution to use `@section Script{...}` in Product.cshtml

Comment: It won't work. `@section` is only allowed in layouts and regular views, so it's not supported in partial-views, editor or display templates. I think you can restructure your js in way that it won't be required to included from the  `Product.cshtml`...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using sections in Editor/Display templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433531/using-sections-in-editor-display-templates)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sections work only in views, not in partials. An editor template is a special kind of partial. It's bad practice to put javascript in partials anyway, so I would simply declare the section in the `Edit.cshtml` view.

But if you very much insist on putting your scripts in the middle of your markup, since Razor doesn't support sections in partials, you could implement [custom helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5433722/29407) to achieve that.