# How do I convert this Razor code from C# to VB.NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-helper

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433531/using-sections-in-editor-display-templates/5433722#5433722) by [Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov) is a great solution to putting javascript into partial views but have them render at a later time.

I've converted the HtmlHelper extensions to VB.NET but I don't know how to use them with Razor.

[image: Extension]

```
@Html.Script(@<script></script>)
```

`Expression expected.`

```
@Html.Script(@:<script></script>)
```

`Expression expected.`

```
@Code
    Html.Script(@<script></script>)
End Code
```

`Expression expected.`

`Syntax error.`

```
@Code
    Html.Script(@:<script></script>)
End Code
```

`Expression expected.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP here. I thought of one solution which is to use Razor Helpers.

**Extensions**

```
Namespace Helpers.Extensions

    Public Module HtmlHelperExtensions

        <Extension>
        Public Function Script(helper As HtmlHelper, result As HelperResult) As MvcHtmlString
            helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items("_script_" & Guid.NewGuid.ToString) = result
            Return MvcHtmlString.Empty
        End Function

        <Extension>
        Public Function RenderScripts(helper As HtmlHelper) As IHtmlString
            helper.ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine("<script type=""text/javascript"">")
            For Each key As Object In helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items.Keys
                If (key.ToString.StartsWith("_script_")) Then
                    Dim result As HelperResult =
                        DirectCast(helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items(key), HelperResult)
                    If result IsNot Nothing Then
                        helper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(result)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            helper.ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine("</script>")
            Return MvcHtmlString.Empty
        End Function

    End Module

End Namespace
```

**Razor (Partial)**

```
@Html.Script(Javascript)

@Helper Javascript()
@<text>
alert("It works");
</text>
End Helper
```

**Razor (_Layout)**

```
@Html.RenderScripts
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [named sections](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx) to define what JavaScript you want rendered in each partial view? It feels like you are trying to replicate this functionality which already exists.

Setup where you want your script to be rendered in your layout. And then you can optionally specify additional scripts in each of your partial views.

**Main View/Layout**

```
<body>
...
  <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/GlobalScript.js")">
  @RenderSection("Javascript", required: false)
</body>
```

**Partial View**

```
@section Javascript
{
  <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/ScriptRequiredByThisPartial.js")"></script>
}
```

Comment: Partials cannot use sections, that's the purpose of this code.