# Should Partial Views contain <head> element

Tags: web, partial-views, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, head

I encounter in some web app that some partial view that is used has head element (it loads some Jquery things).

The thing is that with that and the _layout.xml I get this wierd HTML page structure

```
    <head>
...
    </head>
    <body>
...
    </body>
    <head>
...
    </head>
    <body>
....
    </body>
```

doesn't feel right..

1. What's the best practice to load some .css.js to particular page? is it all done by _layout.xml and bundles?
2. and in general - only _layout.xml should contain head element? no other view in my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want only one head. Use layout with sections and add MVC sections in normal pages to add CSS or JScript. See here on basic section usage http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx. If you want to use partial create a helper to render section from partial see this answer [Using sections in Editor/Display templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433531/using-sections-in-editor-display-templates/5433722#5433722)