# how to have multiple ui panels without duplicating file references

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to write loads of UI partial views as stand alone components that can be used over and over again.  My problem is that I will then need to have jquery references in all the files.  My question is how to handle when a template page which comprises of multiple partial views in one then has multiple references to the same file, see my example below.

```
Partial view A:
- jquerylib.js
- functionsForPanelA.js

Partial view B:
- jquerylib.js 
- functionsForPanelB.js
```

MVC razor page that uses both views:

Template page:

```
@html.renderpartial(Partial view A)

@html.renderpartial(Partial view B)
```

This would then reference jquerylib.js twice..

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you will have to declare the `jquerylib.js` in the view that is rendering those partials. Or maybe use a conjunction of custom helpers that I outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5433722/29407

Comment: if the template page has the jquerylib.js then the component partials won't work independently..??

Comment: No, they won't work independently, but why care? If you want so much to achieve that you will have to use custom helpers as I outlined in my answer. Unfortunately ASP.NET MVC doesn't support defining sections in partials.