# Add JavaScript references based on used ASP MVC EditorFor/Partial template?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am currently using FormFactory (http://formfactory.apphb.com/) to dynamically generate forms for me. This generally works well except for when rending my custom field types which require certain JavaScript files.

What I would like to do is dynamically add JavaScript references to the page depending on what Editor templates have been rendered by FormFactory.

At the moment I am having to reference all JavaScript libraries regardless of whether they are being used. Is there a better way of doing this to ensure that I don't reference libraries which aren't being used?

Edit: Yes, I could add the reference into the EditorFor template, however this would duplicate references if the same template is used more than once.

Thanks

Comment: Please note that this has nothing to do with Classic ASP.  Please retag your question.

Comment: Whoops, don't know how I managed that. Have removed it.

Answer (score 0):

After I realized this also applies to Partial views it was easy to find an answer.

[Using sections in Editor/Display templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433531/using-sections-in-editor-display-templates/5433722#5433722)