# Render partial view in current view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to render a partial view, I am getting no errors or issues other than the graph just no displaying.

Main View

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/Charts/LineChart.cshtml", Model);}
```

Partial View

```
@model IEnumerable<VW_NewVulnerabilities>

<div class="chart">
    <canvas id="lineChart" style="height:250px"></canvas>
</div>
@section scripts {plenty of js in here }
```

All of this worked when it was in one view.
Essentially i am trying to create a dynamic chartjs line chart so i can pass it a list of information and i can reuse it.

Comment: please be careful with your tags.

Comment: How are you specifying you script tags - is the path still correct?

Comment: My script is starting from ~/scripts/ and follow down the same path as it did before. ~ is root correct?

Comment: Move your scripts to the Main View

Comment: Thats mainly the reason why i want the scripts separated is it is alot of code to clutter up a dashboard.
Is there a better way to seperated out the script JS and have the ability to do .net code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use section in partial view, by design, it is the responsibility of the view to set up all the require scripts, not partials.

Having said that, if you want to set script in your partial view, you have to create something like helper to generate, such as this so answer:

[Using sections in Editor/Display templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433531/using-sections-in-editor-display-templates/5433722#5433722)