# How do I emulate RenderSection in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8

I know that sitecore mvc dos't support `RenderSection`.

Is it any way to emulate it with Sitecore MVC ?

I just would like to have only required scripts for specific page.

Of course I can split it to 2 files and to View Rendering but it is seems not good way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not something that you may do easily. It is all about creating appropriate html helpers for that. Here is previous StackOverflow question describing how to implement that:

[Using sections in Editor/Display templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433531/using-sections-in-editor-display-templates/5433722#5433722)

Also this article may help you as well:

http://tomkamphuis.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/sitecore-and-mvc-rendersections.html

Answer (score 2):

What I did to solve this issue was to create add the following Placeholder in my main layout page (for me, at the end of the Javascript script tags)...

```
@Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("javascript")
```

Next add a Sitecore View Rendering that contains the Javascript...

```
@using Sitecore.Mvc
@using Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation
@model RenderingModel
<script>
    $(function () {
        // your javascript
    });
</script>
```

This rendering then gets added to the Design Layout of the content item assigning it to the placeholder "javascript".

As a beginner with Sitecore, I'd be interested what others thought of this solution.

Comment: Yeah this is a simple way of doing it but would it be possible to do the same from let say another rendering? so imagine you want to create a rendering that does X and in that rendering you would want to have some javascript injected in the placeholder javascript?